# Plotly static image generation

Tags: plotly

I am using plotly to generate graphs. So far I had only generated html files and now I am looking into creating image files in png format. I checked this page (https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/) and it looks like newer version of plotly supports this. However, after I setup the new version and all its dependencies when I try running orca it complains with

```
orca
(electron:8968): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I am running on a CentOS on AWS and it does not have any UI. What I am thinking is, is plotly actually trying to open up a web browser just to save an image file? I am on a AWS machine and I don't think opening up a browser is an option. Is there a solution to this or is it only possible to save image files in machines that have a GUI. The idea of being able to save images files only on machines with a GUI does not sound correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out [here](https://github.com/plotly/orca/issues/150#issuecomment-443504666), you should see [here](https://github.com/plotly/orca/blob/80855093193afba09a4dbebaa7bae776be88e15e/README.md#linux-troubleshooting-headless-server-configuration) about using xvfb when you don't have X11 / are headless.